# Viewing SharePoint document in more than one "group by"

Tags: view, grouping, group-by

I will try and explain this as best as I can.

I am a SharePoint moderator for my team. We have over 150 documents/links in 1 central library.

Now based on the certain parameters of a document, it would fall under a certain category and sub-category. To this extent, I have created views/group by to accommodate this needed criteria.

However as an example here is my issue.

If the document name is Apples. I would say categorize this as Loblaws, sub-categorize produce.

With this criteria, the group by would be First Group by Grocery Store (Loblaws) then Group by Aisle (produce).

Since we cannot Group by a column with more than 1 selection, how is it possible to have Apples show up under another group section, say, Sobeys, produce?

I have thought of links, however links cannot have the same name. Is this the only option?